# Unintelligible Error of CloudKit Failing to delete Asset File

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

So, I'm building a simple diary app in which the diary pages are saved in Core Data and synced with CloudKit. I have a lot of database operations, which I do asynchronously in the background. For example, when the user writes an entry, I save the diary page every 5 seconds or when the user adds an image to it.

I do not touch anything with CloudKit rather than using an `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`and these lines:

```
cloudKitContainer.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
guard let containerId = cloudKitContainer.containerIdentifier,
      let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
    print(#function, "Could not initalizeCloudKitScheme.")
    return
}

let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerId)
description.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
```

When saving and deleting diary pages I get the following error. The error occurs especially when adding and deleting images, I guess due to their size:

```
PFCloudKitExporter exportOperationFinished:withSavedRecords:deletedRecordIDs:operationError:]_block_invoke(492): Failed to delete asset file: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D62B434E-A968-423B-8408-9461A97DA8D1/Library/Application%20Support/ckAssetFiles/3F783A57-2038-45E8-8D93-1DD0A7EBD89F.fxd
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“3F783A57-2038-45E8-8D93-1DD0A7EBD89F.fxd” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D62B434E-A968-423B-8408-9461A97DA8D1/Library/Application Support/ckAssetFiles/3F783A57-2038-45E8-8D93-1DD0A7EBD89F.fxd, NSUnderlyingError=0x281995e90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Can anyone explain how this error can occur, if I am only doing basic operations on my dataset?

Comment: I am also having this error.. Are you trying to save an Image in your Core Data (CloudKit) store?

Comment: @MichaelRowe Yes I am, but I'm converting the image into image data and store it as Data. Why do you ask? I have the assumption that this error occurs because the image data is overwritten every 15 seconds and because the image data is so large, iCloud needs some time before it can update. I would assume the error is thrown, when it has not yet updated the last image data, and then it wants to override it, but it can not since it does not exist yet.

Comment: I am also trying to save images in Core Data, I'm trying to move from local files in the App to Core Data so I can sync easily across devices, but it seems that this error is causing some records not to sync.  So any fix you uncover will help.

Comment: @MichaelRowe so you experience errors inside your app? Because I get the error, but my app works and syncs as expected. I will tell you if I find a fix!

Comment: I am finding that only some of my Data actually syncs - it appears to be the larger (newer ) pictures.. I thought about switching to Jpeg instead of PNG, so I could set compression.

Comment: @MichaelRowe I'm using Jpeg, and it does not work. You can try it for yourself, tho. Although if I understand correctly it is not about the images, it is about larger files to sync correctly. I think it is strange that there are no other resources, meaning only a few people have this error...

Comment: @MichaelRowe May I ask you with what frequency do you write the images into the database? Is it one image per hour or do you write like 30 at a time? And what did you set your view context's merge policy to?

Comment: I was doing a one time conversion, so it was about 300 in 3 minutes,, by switching it to JPEG and setting compression to 1.0 it seems to have fixed my problem...